# Android Manifest string resource for parentActivityName?

Tags: android, string, android-manifest, android-resources

On phones I need `Activity C`'s parent to be `Activity B` and on tablets I need `Activity C`'s parent to be `Activity A`. However, I can't set a string resource for the `parentActivityName`. Is there a way to do it via XML? Thanks!

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.ActivityC"

        <!-- @string resource not accepted here -->
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.app.ActivityB">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way. You might do it with your activity itself though. Create a new activity to handle starts on different devices

```
public class ActivityD {
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        boolean isTablet = false || true; // get configuration
        Class<?> activity = isTablet ? ActivityB.class : ActivityA.class;
        startActivity(new Intent(this, activity));
        finish();
    }
}
```

and define it as parent instead

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.app.ActivityC"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.app.ActivityD">
</activity>
```

It's not completely XML, but the best I could think about.